# Training inception-like blocks in Google ML Engine becomes unresponsive

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to train a model with chained blocks similar to Inception's blocks. This models trains fine on my CPU (although, it's a bit slow). When trying to train the same model on ml-engine, the job continues to run, no errors appear in the logs, but training doesn't progress.

#### My model

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
  x = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 199, 199, 1])

  # mini inception block num 1
  conv = tf.layers.conv2d(x, filters=16, kernel_size=1, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
  mp = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(x, pool_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')
  mp = tf.layers.conv2d(mp, filters=16, kernel_size=1, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
  concat = tf.concat([conv, mp], axis=3)

  # mini inception block num 2
  conv = tf.layers.conv2d(concat, filters=32, kernel_size=1, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
  mp = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(concat, pool_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')
  mp = tf.layers.conv2d(mp, filters=32, kernel_size=1, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
  concat = tf.concat([conv, mp], axis=3)

  # ...
```

#### My trainer task

```
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_dir=model_dir, model_fn=model_fn)
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_fn)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=eval_input_fn)

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

#### My ml-engine config

```
trainingInput:
 scaleTier: CUSTOM
 masterType: standard_p100
 workerType: complex_model_m_gpu
 parameterServerType: large_model
 workerCount: 1
 parameterServerCount: 1
```

(I've experimented with `workerCount` as high as 4, and `parameterServerCount` as high as 2)

Here's the bottom of the logs for a particular job:

[image]

#### Question

Why is training getting stuck?

---

As a side note, it seems that some of the log statements issued by Tensorflow is mislabeled as error, when it should probably be info. Example:

> ERROR: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:215] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job master -> {0 -> localhost:2222}

---

#### Edit

After some more testing and experimenting, it seems that the ml-engine job will not get stuck if I apply a simple `tf.reshape()` to the `tf.concat()` that is output from block 1 before using it as input for block 2. The actual shape remains the same, but the job continues to progress.

Comment: Were there any logs for the parameter servers? It looks like there's a chance worker-0 is waiting for the PS

Comment: That's what it looks like. However, the entire job just sat there waiting for one of the nodes (or something) for over 30 minutes. Since there's nothing I can do to shake up any of the server in that cluster, I ended up stopping the job.

Comment: when you tried it locally, did you use `gcloud ml-engine local train --distributed`? If so, did it work there? How many runs did you do without the tf.reshape() and did they all fail?

Comment: I feel it's more like a TensorFlow issue than ML Engine issue. If you can repro it locally as rhaertel80 suggested, then please file an issue to TensorFlow on GitHub. Regarding to the logs mislabeling, we will fix it. Thanks for the feedback.